# Would a fruit cocktail flavoured cake work?

Tags: flavor, cake, fruit, sponge-cake

I am baking a [Cinderella Princes cake](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24723/what-is-the-best-technique-to-put-icing-on-plastic) for my daughter's first birthday party. I have now had the crazy idea of having a [rainbow cake](http://www.incrediblethings.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/rainbow-cake1.jpg) under the skirt of the dress.

Not only this, but I had another crazy idea of making each layer of the rainbow cake taste fruity, in the thought that it would make a fruit cocktail taste.

e.g.

```
Red = Strawberry
Orange = Orange
Green = Kiwi
Yellow = Lemon
Blue = Blueberry
Purple = Blackberry maybe?
```

Would this fruit flavour combination work? Do you know of any similar cakes?

Comment: While you can probably create the layers and have them look and taste well, I am afraid that the combination of 7 tastes in one cake will be too much of a good thing. Also, shaping the layers is going to be a bit hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orange and lemon cakes are classics, so there shouldn't be any problem making those layers. I'm not entirely sure how you'd go about making the others, but there should be a way to incorporate fruit puree into cake batter so that the cakes still rise and set.

Blueberry, blackberry and raspberry can all be added whole or slightly chopped into a cake (think blueberry muffins), although they do make it moister so you'd want to be careful it doesn't end up too wet. This might work for kiwi and strawberry but I've never tried it with anything like those.

You might need a bit of food colouring if you want to emphasise the visual aspects of rainbow layers.

Comment: Yeah I would use food colouring to get the vivid colours, then add the flavouring. Good idea with the blueberry, blackberry and raspberry ( adding chopped bits ). Do you think the mix of flavours would go though?

Comment: You could supplement the fruit flavours with Tutti Fruiti mix or your own hand-chosen mixture of candied peels and fruit and pistachios etc.

Comment: Pistachio would make a better green layer than kiwi

Comment: @ElendilTheTall really liking the idea of a pistachio layer. I'm going to have to make a pistachio cake this weekend I think.

Comment: @5arx yeah I had thought of Tutti Fruiti flavouring, but not sure if this would taste cheap?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall O yeah Pistachio would be an idea. It would add a different dimension to the cake. However I am still unsure whether the mix of flavours would blend together.

Comment: _Fortuna iuvat audentes_ :)

Comment: @TimBJames I would generally say that fruit flavours do blend well, and adding one kind of nut flavour would probably work because fruit and nuts generally go. But as ElendilTheTall says... you have to try it.

Comment: @TimBJames some commercially available tutti-fruitti mixes *do* taste cheap. But you could always try making your own (http://www.ehow.com/how_3910_make-candied-fruit.html makes a reasonable starting point). Things like angelica and maybe a liqueur add much 'class' to the mix ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Well if I were to attempt this I'd try to use jello for the flavor and the color.
Realistically though, the icing and ice cream on the cake are the real flavor aspects.
Lids don't care that you slaved over the oven; put ice cream on anything and they are happy.

After separating the white cake mix into four seperate bowls, add a teaspoon or so of 
the jello mix and stir it in till you get the color you want, then pour the first color in the pan, and each color carefully over top til you get all four layers. Put yellow on top so the icing looks lighter. If I wasn't worried about layers, I'd drag a knife through it and marble it.